# Adding extra params to custom option select html

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working on a custom theme for a client. Is it possible to add extra parameters to the html for the custom options select without having to extend `Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select` or `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`?

I can see in `Mage_Core_Block_Html::_toHtml()` that there is a call to `$this->getExtraParams()` but I can't seem to find anywhere that I would utilize this.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just went ahead an extended the class in a custom module.